# Why choose BigQuery over other RDBMS applications?

Tags: google-bigquery

I was going through the uses of this new technology. However, I have a doubt.

Why should one go for BigQuery over other applications like Teradata or Oracle? What is the advantage of Big Query over these? To be specific, I would like to know, in a data warehousing environment, why and when should one use BigQuery? How will it benefit my business?

Please let me know these ASAP as we might then embrace this new technology.

Regards,
Ria

Answer (score 1):

It of course depends on your needs, but there are number of areas where BigQuery is differentiated from something like Oracle.  Most noteworthy:

- Fast - interactive ad-hoc querying over big data
- Cloud based - no up-front infrastructure costs or management of on-premise hardware
- Scalability - grows as much as you need (Google uses the same technology for its huge amounts of data)

Data warehousing covers quite a lot, and BigQuery currently does not attempt to service all of those needs.  However, it fills a specific set of needs very well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, can you elaborate more, as in, which set of requirement it fulfills or where in the data warehousing process can I integrate it? I also want to know that how to judge whether I should use BigQuery or not.

Comment: Also, for example, we are using Oracle/Teradata as a backend and as an ETL frontend tool we are using DataStage of IBM. And BusinessObjects is fetching data from there. Any idea where can I incorporate BigQuery here and how will it benefit me?